# Skipping through one iteration of a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

Say I had a list:

```
lis = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]
```

And I want to go through each value in the list and double it but If I come across the number 2, after I double it I should skip the next number and only double the on after. For example, in the end my list should look like this.

```
lis = [8, 16, 4, 4, 12]
```

Can this be possible with a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote out a really simple solution that should be easy to understand since it appears you are a beginner

```
lis = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]
new_lis = []
i = 0
while (i < len(lis)):
  new_lis.append(lis[i] * 2)
  if (lis[i] == 2):
    if (i+1 < len(lis)):
        new_lis.append(lis[i+1])
    i = i+1
  i = i+1

print(new_lis)
```

This creates a new list, loops through the old list, appends the doubled value to the new list, skips a number if the value at the index is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm boils down what number you are using to double the items in the list (1 or 2). Here is my take on this problem:

```
lis = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]

def double_with_my_condition(l, doubler=2):
    for i in l:
        yield i * doubler

        if i == 2:
            doubler = 1
            continue

        doubler = 2

new_lis = [*double_with_my_condition(lis)]

print(new_lis)
```

Outputs:

> [8, 16, 4, 4, 12]

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

```
Method-1:
lis = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]
for i in range(len(lis)-1, -1, -1):
    if(lis[i-1] == 2):
        continue
    else:
        lis[i] = lis[i]*2  
lis

Method-2:
lis1 = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]
indices = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(lis1) if x == 2]  #Storing indices of next to 2
lis2 = [i*2 for i in lis1]
for i in indices:
    lis2[i] = lis1[i]  # replacing the previous values

print(lis2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehensions

```
lis = [4, 8, 2, 4, 6]
print([lis[x] if lis[x - 1] == 2 else lis[x] * 2 for x in range(len(lis))])
```